# How come I'm getting this no import error in Django?

Tags: python, mysql, database, django

```
import os
import sys

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = "trade.settings"
from trade.turkey.models import *


d = DemoRecs.objects.all()
d.delete()
```

When I run this, it imports fine if I leave out the `d.delete()` line.  It's erroring on that line. Why? If I comment that out, everything is cool. I can insert. I can update. But when I have that line everything screws up.

The traceback is:

```
 d.delete()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 447, in delete
    obj._collect_sub_objects(seen_objs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 585, in _collect_sub_objects
    for related in self._meta.get_all_related_objects():
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 347, in get_all_related_objects
    self._fill_related_objects_cache()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 374, in _fill_related_objects_cache
    for klass in get_models():
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 167, in get_models
    self._populate()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 61, in _populate
    self.load_app(app_name, True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 76, in load_app
    app_module = import_module(app_name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named turkey
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The directory for the `trade` project is missing from `sys.path`.

Comment: But I can insert stuff into it. (And it actually populates the database). I can also select.

Comment: so it means I actually imported it correctly. (Plus the fact that it didn't boop out on the import line means the sys.path is in there)

Comment: And I printed my sys.path and it's in there.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding "trade" to the pythonpath...

```
import os.path
_pypath = os.path.realpath(os.path.dirname(__file__) + '/trade')
sys.path.append(_pypath)
```

Comment: Thanks, this works, but I accepted Ignacio because he answered it faster :/